# Simple FastWPFGrid MVVM Example

Tags: wpf

I am using the FastWPFGrid control found here:

https://github.com/FormatD/FastWpfGrid

I have looked at the sample applications and while there is a lot there to help with the implementation of the actual grid, I am at a bit of a loss as to how to get the binding to work. I am trying to bind the model of the fastgrid to a property of my datacontext - GridViewModel - this in turn is a view model which inherits from the fastgrid viewmodelbase.

So far, so good. The problem is that when the data changes, the notification isn't happening. See my simple example below. In this example, when I change the number of rows nothing happens. If I manually refresh the xaml (by changing the name of the binding to an invalid one and then back) it then updates. I just need to know how to trigger the notifypropertychanged from code.

I would appreciate a very simple example along the lines of the below:

My Xaml:

```xml
<fastWpfGrid:FastGridControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Model="{Binding SummaryVm}"/>
```

The main viewmodel (the datacontext of my form)

```cs
public SummaryGridViewModel SummaryVm{ get; set; }

//  This Event fires when I know that the row count has changed (for example)
void OnRunListPropertyChanged(Message.RunListPropertyChanged obj)  
{
    // **This is where I need help to get the view to update
}
```

The Grid View Model

```cs
public class SummaryGridViewModel : FastGridModelBase
{
    public SummaryGridViewModel(RunListCalculationQueueManager runList)
    {
        RunList = runList;            
    }

    RunListCalculationQueueManager RunList { get; }

    public override int ColumnCount => 15;

    public override int RowCount => 
        RunList.ActiveRun == null ? 0 : RunList.BaselineRun == null ? 1 : 3;
}
```

So the event in the main viewModel fires as expected, but no change is reflected in the view.

I am not necessarily looking for this code to be fixed, but a simple working example of what I am trying to do would be great.

Comment: What is supposed to be causing the notifications to be raised? In a properly working viewmodel, if you assign a new value to a property `Foo`, the setter raises a `PropertyChanged` event specifying `"Foo"` for the property name. If you add an item to an ObservableCollection or remove one, it raises its `CollectionChanged` event. Are you saying you add an item to `RunList`, or change the `ActiveRun` property of an item in `RunList` and nobody raises a `PropertyChanged` event for `RowCount`? Well, I don't see any mechanism here that *would* raise any such notification.

Comment: Maybe the control doesn't support what you're trying to do "uses MVVM design pattern, but (for performance reasons) does not use classic WPF binding". I dunno what it uses. Quite frankly though. You shouldn't be binding large sets of data.

Comment: @Ed Yes - nothing is happening when I change a property when I change the ActiveRun property. I came to the same conclusion as you that since nothing is raising a notification then there ought to be a way of manually raising one - I have tried calling the property changed notification manually but that doesn't seem to do anything either. I posted on here because I hoped that someone familiar with the control would know how to get it to raise the notification since the documentation for the control is very poor.

Comment: @Tim “tried calling the property changed notification manually” — that tells me nothing about what you actually did. What exactly did you do, where exactly did you do it, and how exactly did you test it?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, it was pretty simple really -

FastGridModelBase exposes several notify methods. Calling

```
SummaryVM.NotifyRefresh
```

caused the notification to fire and everything works well.